# Preventing XSS attach on php script example

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following php pahe which accepts the user's first name and password to access a password protected site.

```
 <?php
    /**
     * ****************************************************************************
     * Micro Protector
     * 
     * Version: 1.0
     * Release date: 2007-09-10
     * 
     * USAGE:
     *   Define your requested password below and inset the following code
     *   at the beginning of your page:
     *   <?php require_once("microProtector.php"); ?>
     * 
     *   See the attached example.php.
     * 
     ******************************************************************************/


    $Password = 'testpass'; // Set your password here



    /******************************************************************************/
       if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){
          $pass = isset($_POST['passwd']) ? $_POST['passwd'] : '';

          if ($pass != $Password) {
             showForm("Wrong password");
             exit();     
          }
       } else {
          showForm();
          exit();
       }

    function showForm($error="LOGIN"){
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
       <title>IMC - Authentication</title>
       <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <Script>
    <!--
    function capitalize(form) {
        value = form.value;
        newValue = '';
        value = value.split(' ');
        for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            newValue += value[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +
            value[i].substring(1,value[i].length) + '';
        }
    newValue = newValue.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    form.value = newValue;
    }
    -->
    </Script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><a href="http://www.test.com"><img src="http://www.test.com/topLogo.png" border=0 /></a></center>
    <br><br><br>
        <div id="main">
          <div class="caption"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
          <div id="icon">&nbsp;</div>
          <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd">
        Your Name:
            <table>
              <tr><td><input class="text" name="name" onBlur="capitalize(this);" maxlength=12 type="text" /></td></tr>
            </table> 
            Password:
            <table>
              <tr><td><input class="text" name="passwd" maxlength=8 type="password" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td align="center"><br/>
                 <input class="text" type="submit" name="submit_pwd" value="Login" />
              </td></tr>
            </table>  
          </form>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php   
    }
    ?>
```

Currently it's not validating any XSS or any type of malicious attack. On my contact us page, i have the following code which ensures the user cannot enter any XSS or any kind of malicious code:

```
// Clean up the input values 
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
  if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) 
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]); 

  $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key])); 
}
```

Can anyone tell me where would I insert the above code in my php page to ensure no code is inserted for malicious intent.

Comment: In a situation like this, XSS isn't something of considerable concern. As the only person who'll be able to see the inserted script is the user themselves, it defeats the purpose of inserting such script, as they could do this using built-in browser dev tools anyway.

Comment: Well first of all you are using HTTPS I hope?

Comment: So what would be the best way to ensure the safety of the website? Its not using HTTPS, is it a requirement as i currently don't have https from the host?

Comment: are you going to store usernames and passwords in a database later? Then you have to be weary of SQL injection attacks. These can be averted by using prepared statements instead of concatenating strings to SQL statements.

Comment: As the code suggests, the user enters the password which will be checked with the php variable to ensure proper access. There is no username involved as it just asks the user their name to make the next page personalized. And the website does not store anything in a database as the password is checked real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a library like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org). It is very easy to use and can filter the user input, preventing XSS attacks.

```
$filter = new HTMLPurifier();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
  $_POST[$key] = $filter->purify($_POST[$key])); 
}
```

then you can check the password against the one in your database or other storage mechanism

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where would i add it in my page above?

Comment: You will need to first download the library and save it in your project folder. Then you will need to include the autoloader of HTMLPurifier (instructions are very clear in their site) at the top of your page. Create an object as I showed you at the top, of the page and then when you process the POSTed data, use the snippet (foreach) I provided above.